# Where do people get web design patterns/inspiration from?

Tags: design-patterns, inspiration

I like to think I come up with original concepts as and when I can but I do find it really gives me a kick start when I can see examples of what other people have been doing to inspire my own design process. I thought it might be good to post a question providing links to some of the best design pattern/inspiration web sites I have come across in the past.

Here are some that I use quite frequently, probably in order of most used:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/

http://patterntap.com/

http://patternry.com/?page=1

http://konigi.com/

http://www.designfridge.co.uk/

Does anyone have any others to add to this list?

Answer (score 3):

**Here's a great collection of pattern resources by smashing magazin:**

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/

**And one by Yahoo:**

http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/

Comment: THX :) an upvote and that's all :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a collection of this kind of patterns/inspiration sites at
http://profs.info.uaic.ro/~evalica/patterns/
Hope to be useful

Comment: Thanks, never come across this before....this is really handy, lots to get through here.

Answer (score 1):

Anders Toxboe has put together a pretty good site for UI-Patterns - http://ui-patterns.com/.

Answer (score 0):

James Melzer also put together a bundle of links:
http://jamesmelzer.com/interaction-design/patterns-resources

Comment: Interesting, this is pretty similar to what I've been tasked with...makes for an interesting read! Thanks

Comment: Link now shows just a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

[UX Pond](http://www.uxpond.com) provides a search facility that looks at all these UI pattern sites at once.

Comment: This is cool, I've used the logo version of this hadn't seen this one before though.