# website for ui design inspiration

Tags: gui-design, inspiration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do people get web design patterns/inspiration from?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6030/where-do-people-get-web-design-patterns-inspiration-from)

Is there a web site for UI design inspirations? I'm looking for something dedicated to UX and UI...that would show screenshots like this link:

http://designmodo.com/login-form-examples/

The above shows some examples of new login form designs...I'm looking for this sort of level of inspiration but for other areas of a site.

Seems like this site should exist somewhere out there on the interwebs already.

**Update:** Here is a running list:

http://www.uiparade.com/
http://patterntap.com/

Answer (score 0):

The simpler and easier to read, the better!.. Users should be provided with the simplest and fastest method for logging in.

Comment: yeah. i'm specificially doing password reset form, but I'm curious if a site exists that has a ton of ideas.

Comment: Try visiting some of the most popular websites and see how they handle password resets. That should give you good ideas on how you want to design yours. Most sites send an email to the registered address, then you click on the link provided in the email.